# SVG resource creates indefinite number of HTTP requests/calls

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

In Chrome (Version 94.0.4606.81) one specific SVG file is loaded indefinitely (creating indefinite number of HTTP requests). I cannot figure out why this happens only on Chrome (could not reproduce it on Firefox).

You can see the bug behavior on this website/template yourself: http://www.ansonika.com/fooyes/

1. To reproduce it, open chrome DevTools->Network and go to the above website.
2. Soft-Refresh the page couple of times: 3-4 times.

As soon as you refresh it, you will notice thousands of requests per second for the resource wave_white.svg all loaded from memory cache.

The CSS:

```
.wave {
    width: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    /*height from the svg file*/
    height: 65px;
    top: -65px;
    left: 0;
    background: url("../img/wave_white.svg");
    z-index: 99;
    animation: waves 20s linear infinite;
}
.wave:before, .wave:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    background: url("../img/wave_white.svg");
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.wave:before {
    opacity: 0.4;
    animation: waves-reverse 20s linear infinite;
}
.wave:after {
    opacity: 0.6;
    animation-delay: -5s;
    animation: waves 30s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: To report Chrome bugs: https://crbug.com

Comment: @kaiido I'm not sure it's a chrome bug, maybe it's the css. I believe it has something to do with the animation property.

Comment: It happens only sporadically: it's a Chrome bug. It can't be reproduced on other browsers: it's a Chrome bug. It entered an infinite loop of requests from CSS: it's Chrome bug. Please report it.

Comment: Reproducible in Chrome and Edge, not in FireFox, so its a Chromium bug

Comment: After you report it, please post a link to the bug report here. For the benefit of future readers.

Comment: Same issue here, have you found a solution?